# Sharepoint: Site List not showing?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

So I have site list on certain pages that basically just have links to other pages. I have a group that has contribute( Can view, add, update, and delete) access to the site and they can't see any of the links in my site list. They only are able to see the links when I give the group design( Can view, add, update, delete, approve, and customize) access. Well I don't really want to give them approve and customize access.

Anyone know why contribute access is not letting them see the links?

This is sharepoint 2007 btw.

Comment: Are these links to other pages inside of the SharePoint site?  Is this a collaboration site or publishing portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the list has content approval turned on (and draft security set to the default of only allowing people with approve rights to see draft items) and the items hasn't been approved